# Instant redirect without prompt when clicking an <a> tag inside an AMP Story html content

Tags: amp-html, amp-ad

When i click on a link tag inside an AMP Story Page, a prompt is opened first and when clicking on prompt then the page redirects. Is there a way to instantly redirect when clicking on a link inside the AMP page without the prompt?
https://pasteboard.co/IyTglV9.png

I have tried to use the on="tap" event to capture the click and then with the 
.

AMP.navigateTo(URL=STRING, target=STRING, opener=BOOLEAN)

tried to navigate to the URL, but in the console it throws some unexpected error

Invalid action definition in  ​Subscribe​​ : [ tap:AMP.navigateTo(https://apto.gr, _blank, true) ] ; expected [=]

Obviously when i change the : to = it throws the opposite error 
...  ; expected [:]

This is the code i am using

```
<button on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(https://apto.gr, _blank, true)" href="https://apto.gr" target="_blank" class="adBtn i-amphtml-error" style="color:#f30809;background:#000000;">Subscribe</button>
```

Using a tag has the same result.

```
<a on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(https://apto.gr, _blank, true)" href="https://apto.gr" target="_blank" class="adBtn i-amphtml-error" style="color:#f30809;background:#000000;">Subscribe</a>
```

Am i doing something wrong with the AMP.navigateTo code? I think that this is my solution but i cannot make the action to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable  the redirect prompt in AMP stories body, unless you use `amp-story-cta-layer`

Why?

When AMP gurus designed AMP stories, they were worried what would happen if user clicks by accident links on the story and they get redirected, hence annoying them. That's why they added the prompt by default.

The only links that can be tapped and redirected without prompt are those located inside `amp-story-cta-layer`. It must be the last element of your `amp-story-page` and by default it takes 100% of the width and 20% of the height of the story and it sticks to the bottom. This way there is almost no way of accidentally clicking.

Here is the code:

```
<amp-story-cta-layer>
    <a href="https://www.ampproject.org" class="button">Your link without prompt here</a>
</amp-story-cta-layer>
```

`[image]

[You can watch this lecture for more info.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXJGZr2iZa8)

Comment: This worked as expected. Also i observed that with some use of CSS we can replace the default style that attach everything only at bottom and have the outlinks zone as you mentioned wherever we want without any problem! Just by wrapping everything in the amp-story-cta-layer and then force relative position the tag, everything works like a charm, without even braking the amp validation process!

Comment: Also just for future people reading this, according to AMP
[amp-story-cta-layer] amp-story-cta-layer is not allowed on the first page of an amp-story.
So you can use this after the first story page

Comment: @AgamemnonKatradis Good to know! 

It is good that you managed to move the `amp-story-cta-layer` HOWEVER, I wouldn't recommend people doing that. Quoting from the docs "Positioning and sizing of this layer cannot be controlled. It is always 100% width of the page, 20% height of the page, and aligned to the bottom of the page. " 

So hacking the positioning with CSS even if it works for now might have bad consequences, namely your `cta-layer` being moved out of the sudden without you knowing. It is best to go with the framework's requirements / recommendations to avoid disasters .

Comment: You are absolutely right. But what practice you think we should follow when the customer that needs the platform i work on wants to have links without the prompt? Of course AMP is based on strict guidelines, but nonetheless sometimes what they expect there in google may be different sometimes in the actual world, don't you think?